# Change location of wc_print_notice in Woocommerce cart

Tags: woocommerce, cart, notice

When I update my cart (remove product or change quantity) I get a green update message inside the cart table:

[image].

Now I would like to get this message outside the table in full width as you can see with the coupon code example:

[image: See coupon code message example]

I know it has something to do with the hooks `woocommerce_before_cart_table` and `woocommerce_before_cart`.

**This is the div line I want to reposition:**

```
<div class="woocommerce-message message-wrapper" role="alert">
    <div class="message-container container success-color medium-text-center">
    <i class="icon-checkmark"></i>Cart updated.
</div>
```

**Update:**
This is a snipped of my themes cart.php.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>
<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
<div class="woocommerce row <?php echo $row_classes; ?>">
<div class="col large-7 pb-0 <?php echo $main_classes; ?>">
```

wc_print_notice is placed in the right position. This did change the coupon code to go full width but not the updated cart messages.

Comment: By default `wc_print_notices()` is located just before `woocommerce_before_cart` and it's displayed in full with by default in Woocommerce… **The guilty is your theme!** It is surely customizing the `cart/cart.php` template located in a **"woocommerce"** subfolder. So you will have to find the function `wc_print_notices();` and to move it back in the right place like in [the **original Woocommerce template** file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/ed634df65ae45efe33f1ff8a77fa0ed951b81dd9/templates/cart/cart.php).

Comment: Please don't put raw code in the comments as it's unreadable… Is better to add it in your question as an edit…